# How to add child views to a LinearLayout in reverse order?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I am dynamically creating `TextViews` and adding those views in a `LinearLayout`. 
**I want to show the recently added `TextView` to the user.** 
But the problem is that the `LinearLayout` is adding the views in a top-down manner. 
How can I add the child views in reverse order ?

Comment: Hi, if you add some code you will help us to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`ViewGroup.addView(View child, int index)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#addView(android.view.View,%20int)) method. You can insert the newest TextView at the top of LinearLayout.